# Getting maven error on mvn clean build for a project using commons-beanutils - 'parent.artifactId' must be changed

Tags: java, maven

Here is mulesoft based maven project and ran with command  "mvn -X clean install" and the build fails with 'parent.artifactId' must be changed, how do I track and resolve the error.  The commons-logging downloads.  Also, commons-parent downloads to local repository but still don't see what the error is and how to fix

The the build fails with the following error:

WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3626113Z [FATAL] 'parent.artifactId' must be changed, the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project. @

Here is part of the dependency tree

```
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-validation-module:jar:mule-plugin:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
```

Here is the error with debug enabled.

```
2019-09-19T21:42:05.2870015Z Downloaded from central: http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/8/project-8.pom (35 kB at 1.3 MB/s)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.2870363Z [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/8/_remote.repositories
2019-09-19T21:42:05.2876255Z [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/8/project-8.pom.lastUpdated
2019-09-19T21:42:05.2975015Z [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/
2019-09-19T21:42:05.2976429Z [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/
2019-09-19T21:42:05.2977199Z Downloading from central: http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.pom
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3047240Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (4.1/19 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3050582Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (7.8/19 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3054356Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (12/19 kB) 
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3057335Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (16/19 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3229423Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (19 kB)   
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3229897Z                                              
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3230797Z [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected 075c03ba4b01932842a996ef8d3fc1ab61ddeac2 but is 6823fb52ed23861f0b46c247e2d0bbff5510b398 from central for http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.pom
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3305334Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (4.1/19 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3308907Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (7.8/19 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3312625Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (12/19 kB) 
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3316742Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (16/19 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3425761Z Progress (1): commons-logging-1.2.pom (19 kB)   
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3426873Z [WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.pom
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3428984Z org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, expected 075c03ba4b01932842a996ef8d3fc1ab61ddeac2 but is 6823fb52ed23861f0b46c247e2d0bbff5510b398
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3435423Z     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validateExternalChecksums (ChecksumValidator.java:174)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3440358Z     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validate (ChecksumValidator.java:103)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3444416Z     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3447867Z     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3451475Z     at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3454708Z     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3456941Z     at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:259)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3459419Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3461936Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3470505Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3494763Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3501673Z     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3503236Z     at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3503631Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3537465Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:522)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3539242Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:411)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3540350Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3541338Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3542292Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:507)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3543487Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:460)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3544534Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3545671Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3546927Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:507)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3547929Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:460)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3548865Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3549837Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3550794Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:507)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3551747Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:460)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3552714Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3553945Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3554960Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3556128Z     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3557129Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:202)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3558078Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3559220Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.resolveExtensionArtifacts (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:910)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3560234Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupExtensionsRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:841)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3561209Z     at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.createProjectRealm (DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:197)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3562188Z     at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultModelBuildingListener.buildExtensionsAssembled (DefaultModelBuildingListener.java:100)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3563249Z     at org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingEventCatapult$1.fire (ModelBuildingEventCatapult.java:44)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3564480Z     at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.fireEvent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1348)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3565568Z     at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:443)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3566561Z     at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:423)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3574950Z     at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:580)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3576229Z     at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:372)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3577236Z     at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:400)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3583109Z     at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:391)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3615097Z     at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:78)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3615784Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:511)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3618209Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:221)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3618481Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3618642Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3618954Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3619138Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3619324Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3619477Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3619661Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3619853Z     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3620013Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3620194Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3620381Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3620579Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3620762Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3620936Z                                              
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3622494Z [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected 075c03ba4b01932842a996ef8d3fc1ab61ddeac2 but is 6823fb52ed23861f0b46c247e2d0bbff5510b398 from central for http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.pom
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3623464Z Downloaded from central: http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.pom (19 kB at 325 kB/s)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3624062Z [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /root/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/_remote.repositories
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3624674Z [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /root/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.pom.lastUpdated
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3625454Z [WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3626113Z [FATAL] 'parent.artifactId' must be changed, the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project. @ 
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3626248Z 
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3626810Z [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3627503Z [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3628373Z Downloading from central: http://somehost.some.com:8081/repository/mulesoft-group/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.pom
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3688093Z Progress (1): commons-codec-1.10.pom (4.1/12 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3690839Z Progress (1): commons-codec-1.10.pom (7.8/12 kB)
2019-09-19T21:42:05.3805171Z Progress (1): commons-codec-1.10.pom (12 kB)
```

Comment: you have 2 problems, the first one, you reposoitory has artifacts where the jar doesnt match with their .md5 and sha1, but that is only a warning, sencond one, you have 2 poms a parent and a module but both have the same artifactId, they have to have differente id in order to maven handle them as diferent artifacts

Comment: Does that mean two poms, maybe commons-parent and commons-logging.  The pom file has artifactid with commons-logging and commons-logging.

Comment: This is the answer, can you post.  Apparently we must have manually edit the pom where the parent matched the current module.  But it was tricky because these are all third-party dependency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems, the first one, you repository has artifacts where the jar doesn't match with their .md5 and sha1, but that is only a warning, second one, you have 2 poms a parent and a module but both have the same artifactId, they have to have different id in order to maven handle them as different artifacts.

The issue was around an internal commons logging repository where the parent id was actually commons logging and shouldn't have been, should have been commons-parent.